# Subsitute decimal point in floating point number with comma Python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nlp

For a given string, how can we substitute the decimal point in a floating point number with a comma?

For example: `12.33` should become `12,33`

Please note that I can not simply replace all the `.` with `,` since the text also contains full stops to separate two sentences.

I need this for a text cleaning purpose.

Comment: Where's your attempt?

Comment: Does the floating point number always have at least one digit after the decimal point?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use 2 capturing groups and assert what is on the left and on the right is not a non whitespace char.

```
(?<!\S)(\d+)\.(\d+)(?!\S)
```

In parts

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ digits
- `\.` Match dot literally
- `(\d+)` Capture **group 2**, match 1+ digits
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookbehind, what is directly on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2qAlJ/1)

In the replacement use group 1 and group 2 and place the comma between the groups

```
\1,\2
```

For example

```
import re

text = "Test 12.33 test"
new_text = re.sub(r'(?<!\S)(\d+)\.(\d+)(?!\S)', r'\1,\2', text)
print(new_text)
```

Output

```
Test 12,33 test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `finditer` to find all the positions of matches in the text.
Then replace them one by one.

```
import re

text = '''This is a dummy text. I want the `.` of 12.12 to go away. 
I want to replace it with a `,`. Lets see if it works.'''

p = re.compile(r"\d\.\d")
for m in p.finditer(text):
    text = text[:m.start() + 1] + ',' + text[m.start() + 2:]

print(text)
```

The output is

```
This is a duppy text. I want the `.` of 12,12 to go away. 
I want to replace it with a `,`. Lets see if it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply this simple regex substitution expression

```
re.sub(r'(\d+)\.(\d*)', r'\g<1>,\g<2>',search_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using the following regular expression:

`decmark_reg = re.compile('(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)')`